# How can I calculate annual energy demand (kWh) used by a three-phase data centre?

Tags: three-phase

I have output parameters from a data centre which details three phases:

```
Output voltage phase (V) = 239.00 | 239.0 | 239.0
Current phase (A) = 8.0 | 8.0 | 10.0
Power phase (W) = 1600 | 1600 | 2200
```

I understand the output load is 20%

Would it be a case of calculating 20% of the total power across phases (5400W) then multiplaying by uptime (e.g. 7,752 hours) to get a good approximate value of kWh?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think your third current reading is incorrect.

Comment: Good spot @Andyaka, updated.

Comment: Good is very subjective given you have one data point.  It will give you an approximate value, but it's accuracy is debatable.  As Andy says, more readings will give you greater accuracy.  Even sampled once an hour for 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Would it be a case of calculating 20% of the total power across phases
> (5400W) then multiplying by uptime (e.g. 7,752 hours) to get a good
> approximate value of kWh?*

It would likely be a poor estimation. For sure, at the moment those readings were taken, the power consumption would have been 5400 watts but that's all you have provided and it's all we know. Who is to say that the power of 5400 watts was a good representation of the 20% load? Who is to say that the up-time of 7752 hours (323 days) is at all representative of the real up-time? Who can say that the 20% figure is at all meaningful of a sustained real-life situation?

Get a kilowatt hour meter is my advice. Even the cheapest one will give a better result than an estimation based on the information you have provided. More readings and more data = more accuracy and a more reliable prediction.

Comment: Thanks Andy aka - This is currently for a back of napkin calculation, I wanted to check the method was reasonable in case something strange was going on with that three phrase input.